# Store Alphabet Only

Tags: c, data-structures

I have data declared as a `char name[20]`, but my program can read numbers when the user key in the input.  A message should appear if not valid or does not have enough space. Got a way to solve my problem?

My code also reads more than 20 characters and appears weird symbols when characters of more than 20. I use some repetition code under this program for data structure

```
printf("Insert Name: ");
while (scanf(" %[^\n]s", name) != 1) {
  printf("Name you insert not valid! Please insert name: ");
  while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Comment: Please change `scanf(" %[^\n]s", name)` to `scanf(" %19[^\n]", name)`. Two changes a) limit the input, and b) format `%[]` is NOT a subset of format `%s` . They are quite different specifiers.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect it to reject numbers. This: say `12345` is just characters at the point of input. They are valid to store in a string as with any other characters.

Comment: Real-life names can contain digits, spaces, punctuation, and all sorts of weird characters.

Comment: Maybe users wrongly type name like this '1Angela'. Thats why i need the system reject the input

Answer (score 2):

> My code also reads more than 20 characters and appears weird symbols

`scanf(" %[^\n]s", name)` does not prevent too many characters from being read into `name`.  This leads to *undefined behavior* (UB) and all sorts of troubles.  Review `scanf()` documentation for *width* and proper specifiers.

---

- Stop using `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.  Use `fgets()` to read a line of user input.  Use `strcspn()` to lop off a trailing `'\n'`.
- Separate user input from validation.
- Use `isalpha()` to detect letters.  Use `isdigit()` to detect digits.
- Use various tests on input to assess its acceptability.  See [Name validation best practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/330518/94903).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
...
    char buf[BUFSIZ];  // BUFSIZ (from <stdio.h>) is at least 256.
    char name[20] = "";
    printf("Insert Name: ");
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
      buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; // Lop off potential `\n`.

      // Length check
      size_t len = strlen(buf);
      if (len >= sizeof name) {
        printf("Name too long! Please insert name: ");
        continue;
      }
        
      // Content check
      // Re-work as needed - maybe accept spaces?
      bool content_OK = len > 0;
      for (size_t i = 0; buf[i] && content_OK; i++) {
        unsigned char ch = buf[i];
        if (!isalpha(ch)) {
          content_OK = false;
        }
      }
      if (!content_OK) {
        printf("Name has non-letters! Please insert name: ");
        continue;
      }

      strcpy(name, buf);
      // Use `name`. 
    }
```

I would put this code to read a *name* into a helper function.

Comment: Any reason for using `BUFSIZ` here? That seems like a constant intended for a different use case.

Comment: @templatetypedef `BUFSIZE` is the size of the buffer used by the `setbuf`
function.  It affords a 256+ value that tends to scale with the size the system.  To read a _line_, some value in the dozens to hundreds is useful to read a _name_ and with extra to boot.  A more formal answer might use `#define NAME_SIZE_MAX 100` and an buffer 2x that.  IAC, OP's 20 is far too small except for trivial learner's code - such as this.  I'm trying to get OP off using wee buffers and simply grabbed a convenient size.

Comment: My code is unable to run. do you have any email that can reach you? it keeps continuing. when I put the break, it will skip my next line to enter from the user input line.

Comment: @Will44447777, _Append_ to your post a [mcve] with sample input data, output seen and output desired.